# Prove the following for the relation of equivalence.

Tags: general-topology

We define the following equivalence relation on ${\mathbb{R}}^{2}$

$$(x,y) \sim (X,Y)  $$ if and only if y=Y

and

$$(x,y) \Join (X,Y) $$ if and only if $${x}^{2} + {y}^{2}= {X}^{2}+{Y}^{2}$$

Prove the following
$${\mathbb{R}}^{2}/\sim \cong \mathbb{R}$$

and
$${\mathbb{R}}^{2}/\Join \cong [o,\infty)$$

Please help...

Comment: What does $\underline{\propto}$ mean?

Comment: Don't really know but it is on the online notes, i guess proportional or equal?

Comment: whoops i wrote the wrong symbol, ill edit it

Comment: Ok :). I guess it has to be an isomorphism of some sort...

Comment: @Abel, I think he means homeomorphism.

Comment: i've got so many notes... i have a lot of stuff written about homeomorphisms?

Comment: @Andy Probably. I guess I'll assume that for now :)

Answer (score 1):

The equivalence classes of $\sim$ will be the horizontal lines in the plane. As a representative of each class, we can take the $y$-intercept. The quotient, then "squeezes" the plane into the $y$-axis, which is effectively the real line.

The equivalence classes of $\Join$ will be the circles about the origin of non-negative radius. As a representative of each class, we can take the point of the class on the non-negative $x$-axis, which will be of the form $\langle r,0\rangle$, where $r$ is the radius of the circle. You can picture the quotient "tearing" the plane along the negative $x$-axis and then "squeezing" the torn plane into the non-negative $x$-axis, which is effectively the ray $[0,\infty)$.

That's the general idea. You'll need to work out the details, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}^2/\sim\to\mathbb{R}\colon [(x,y)]\mapsto y$ and $\psi\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2/\sim\colon y\mapsto[(0,y)]$.

Can you show that $\phi$ is well defined?

Can you show that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are each others inverse?

If necessary:
Can you see that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are both continuous?

For the second part take $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}^2/\Join\to[0,\infty)\colon[(x,y)]\mapsto\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\psi\colon[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^2/\Join\colon x\mapsto[(x,0)]$.

The same question apply here.

Comment: thank you  this really helps